# Adding database results to array of objects in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been working on this for a while now and I cannot seems to find a good/proper way to add objects coming from a DB query to an array holding objects. Please note I am developing a React Native Expo application.

This is basically the code that I have

```
  var arr = [];

firebase.firestore().collection('Something').where("text", "==" , "text").get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
      arr += doc.data();
    })
})
```

The idea here is to have `arr` populated with the object result of `doc.data()`. I have looked at a million (if felt like it) tutorials, but I cannot seems to figure out the proper and correct way to populate my array.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, doc.data() returns objects and you want to populate the array with those objects?

If that is so, try replacing `arr += doc.data();` with `arr.push(doc.data())`